# How to join using two intermediate tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I don't have much experience on database design and I'm in trouble trying to solve this. I've spent many hours and nothing good so far.
So the idea is to be able to assign multiple values to multiply fields in the main table.

Here is an image to give you the idea.

[image]

1) How to design it while preserving data integrity?
2) Do I have to use two intermediate tables?
3) If so, how am I going to query two intermediate tables at the same query? does this make any sense?

Any suggestion to help point me in the right direction would be much appreciated and can save me from pulling my hair & going bald prematurely :)

EDIT:
Something like this, but I have a feeling my design here is wrong.
I need to display all fields from ub_properties and all fields from oub_level_two and ub_utility.
[image]

Comment: What is your question?  Perhaps sample data and desired results would help us figure out what you want to do.

Comment: You should probably not design it in a tuple format. Use a typical ERD that will show the relationships (1:1, 1:M, M:N). Then you should have no problem finding the best solution for those cases.

Comment: This is a bit vague. Please add example data. No idea what values and option should represent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *1) How to design it while preserving data integrity?*
>
> *2) Do I have to use two intermediate tables?*

Yes, you need two intermediate tables. Your design is good if you want to allow same values and options in properties rows. If you don't want to allow that, then get rid of the `id` columns in the intermediate tables and make both fields as the primary key.

> *3) If so, how am I going to query two intermediate tables at the same query? does this make any sense?*

You can make one query using joins like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ub_properties p
LEFT JOIN ub_level_two_meta lm ON lm.post_id = p.post_id
LEFT JOIN ub_level_two l ON l.id = lm.level_two_id
LEFT JOIN ub_utility_meta um ON um.post_id = p.post_id
LEFT JOIN ub_utility u ON u.id = um.utility_id
```

Comment: This looks promising, I think we are into something here. I'm just testing it with different configurations and will post back once done.

Comment: Thanks again, this pointed me in the right direction and with some changes, I finally solved the query problem. I actually changed the entire schema design after I got to understand some of the design concepts ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is that you seem to need five tables, three entity tables and two junctions tables:

- MainTable, which is in green
- Values
- MainValues, which has one row for each MainTable.id and value corresponding to that id.
- Options
- MainOptions, which has one row for each MainTable.id and option corresponding to that id.

You can then use these in queries using joins.

Comment: thanks. that's something I have been trying to do and couldn't get it right. I have just edited my original post here, to give you a better idea about what I'm currently trying to do.

I use JOIN beteen ub_properties, ub_level_two and ub_level_two_meta but when I add the other two tables to the join, I always get different kind of errors.